# Python 2.7 lambda expression issue

Tags: python, python-2.7, lambda

For Python 2.7, what is the logic of below lambda expression, confused by this part `int(s)`, it seems no variable called s.

```
x = [tuple(map(lambda s: int(s), x.split(':'))) for x in y.split(' ')]
```

thanks in advance,
Lin

Comment: That's the argument it's passing to `lambda` function.

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, but might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/890128/why-are-python-lambdas-useful?lq=1

Comment: @Kasramvd, thanks and vote up. So the code just do explicit type conversion for each item returned from `x.split(':')` and form a tuple?

Comment: @Michael0x2a, thanks and vote up. So the code just do explicit type conversion for each item returned from `x.split(':')` and form a tuple?

Comment: @LinMa Yup, exactly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `lambda` function was used with `map`, so the parameters for the `lambda` are passed from the second argument of `map`. Understanding how `map` works will help you understand better how the lambda takes its parameter:

> Apply function to **every item** of `iterable` and return a list of the
>   results. If additional iterable arguments are passed, function must
>   take that many arguments and is applied to the items from all
>   iterables in parallel

So `s` represents each item from the iterable `x.split(':')` and `int(s)` implies an explicit cast of item `s` to integer, where `int(x)` is the return object of the `lambda`.

You may read more about [`lambda`](http://www.diveintopython.net/power_of_introspection/lambda_functions.html) and [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map)

Comment: Thanks Moses, vote up. So the code just do explicit type conversion for each item returned from `x.split(':')` and form a tuple?

Comment: Exactly. You've worded it better than I have done